# How to update an item in Firestore RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to update an item in my `RecyclerView` with a save button in the toolbar which calls `updateQuestion()`.

I have this structure in my Firebase:

`Questions`

-->`list_of_documents wUniqueIDs`

--->fields in documents:

+`question`

+`answer`

+`rating`

so far i have this under `updateQuestion()`

```
private void updateQuestion() {
        String questionString = mQuestionTextView.getText().toString();
        Object updatedText = mQuestionEditText.getText().toString();
        String questionPath2 = rootRef.collection("Questions").document().getPath();

        FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        CollectionReference collectionReference = rootRef.collection(questionPath2).document().update("question", updatedText); // <--- I GET ERROR HERE
}
```

```
error: incompatible types: Task<Void> cannot be converted to CollectionReference
```

I also got an error previously saying that the second parameter for `update()` needs to be an object however this error has seemed to disappear.

I've been trying to follow tutorials and looking at other posts on stackOverflow but none seem to address this.

Here is what i've tried previously:

```
//        CollectionReference ref = rootRef.collection("Questions").document().collection("question");
//        CollectionReference ref = rootRef.collection("Questions").document().collection(questionPath);

//        Toast.makeText(this, "this is the path: " + questionPath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//        Log.d(TAG, "updateQuestion: " + ref.get(question.getAnswer));
//        Log.d(TAG, "updateQuestion: " + ref.collection(questionPath).document("question", questionPath).toString())
//        Log.d(TAG, "updateQuestion: " + ref.document(questionPath)("question").toString());
//        Log.d(TAG, "updateQuestion: " + ref.document(questionPath).get(question).toString());
//        ref.collection("question")
//        db.child("Spacecraft").push().setValue(spacecraft);
//        rootRef.collection("Questions").document().update("question", updatedText);
//        rootRef.collection("Questions").document(questionPath).update("question", updatedText);

//        TextView savedText = mQuestionTextView.setText(updatedText);

//        DocumentReference documentReference = rootRef.collection("Questions").document(questionPath).update("question", );
//        DocumentReference documentReference = rootRef.document(questionPath).update("question", updatedText);
//        CollectionReference collectionReference = rootRef.collection(questionPath).document().update("question", updatedText);
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

------------------ **Revised Code as of 2019 - 04 - 07 @ 1153pm** ---------

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.save_question:
                mShowSaveIcon = false;
                updateQuestion();
                break;

            case R.id.edit_question:
                item.setVisible(false);
                enableEditMode();
                mShowSaveIcon = true;
                break;

        }
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        return true;
    }

    private void enableEditMode(){

        mQuestionEditText = findViewById(R.id.questionEditTextID);
        mPostAnswerButton.setEnabled(false);
        mPostAnswerButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.darker_gray));

        mCommentButton.setEnabled(false);
        mCommentButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.darker_gray));

        String questionString = mQuestionTextView.getText().toString();
        mQuestionTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mQuestionEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mQuestionEditText.setText(questionString);
    }



    private void updateQuestion(){
        Question question = createQuestionObj();
        updateQuestionToCollection(question);
    }

    private Question createQuestionObj(){
        final Question question = new Question();
        return question;
    };

private void updateQuestionToCollection(Question question) {
        String questionString = mQuestionTextView.getText().toString();
        Object updatedText = mQuestionEditText.getText().toString();


        FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        String docId = rootRef.collection("Questions").document().getId();
        System.out.println(docId);
        String questionPath = rootRef.collection("Questions").document(docId).collection("question").getPath();
//        String questionPath2 = rootRef.collection("Questions").document(docId).getPath();

        System.out.println(questionPath);
        rootRef.collection(questionPath).document(docId).update("question", updatedText).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: it worked");
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: it failed because of: " + e.toString());
            }
        });

finish();
 }
};
```

**DataBase Structure Snippet Below**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I'm looking at your code I see two problems. The first one is the following error:

```
error: incompatible types: Task<Void> cannot be converted to CollectionReference
```

Which is produced because when you are calling `update()` method on a `DocumentReference` object, the object that is returned is of type `Task<Void>` and **not** `CollectionReference`. Please also note that there is no way in Java in which you can cast an CollectionReference object to a Task. So to solve this, just remove the declaration of your `collectionReference` object like this:

```
rootRef.collection(questionPath2).document("specificDocId").update("question", updatedText);
```

The second issue is that you are generating a new document id each time you are calling `updateQuestion()` since you aren't passing any id to the `document()` method. To be able to update a specific document, you need to pass the actual id of document so it can be updated:

```
rootRef.collection(questionPath2).document("specificDocId").update("question", updatedText);
```

**Edit:**

In order to update a document use this reference:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference questionsRef = rootRef.collection("questions");
DocumentReference docRef = questionsRef.document("yCCRgoRIAmtmKmTFLYJX");
docRef.update("question", updatedText);
```

Comment: I updated my code per your suggestion and a couple other discoveries. I added an on completeListener and onFailureListener and found this error when i tried to save my update: `D/QuestionProfileActivity: onFailure:  failed because of: com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: NOT_FOUND: No document to update: projects/stairmasterapp/databases/(default)/documents/Questions/yCCRgoRIAmtmKmTFLYJX/question/yCCRgoRIAmtmKmTFLYJX`. I have the path pointing to the field:"question" inside the document of Questions.

Comment: Please show me your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: It worked with a small tweak!

Had to change: 
`DocumentReference docRef = questionsRef.document("yCCRgoRIAmtmKmTFLYJX");
`

to this:

`DocumentReference docRef = questionsRef.document("FUaCgO8CmTLDYpECsnzK"); // <----to this
`

Comment: I did not update directly on the RecyclerAdapter and the data on Firestore update too?

Comment: FirestoreRecyclerAdapter